# I keep receiving command not found when I try to run my code in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, bc

I am trying to write a code that will calculate the radius and area of a circle using pi and the circumference. When I try to run my code, I receive an error message that says

```
main.sh: line 5: bc: command not found
main.sh: line 7: bc: command not found
```

Could you please advise me on where I went wrong, and help me to fix my code?

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash
pi=3.14;
circumference=5;
echo "$circumference"
radius=$(echo "$circumference" \* 2 \* "$pi" |bc -l);
echo "$radius"
area=$(echo "$pi" \* "$radius" \* "$radius" |bc -l);
echo "$area"
echo "The radius of a circle is $radius";
echo "The area of a circle is $area";
exit
```

Comment: When I remove the bc -l, it just prints 5 *3.14 instead of doing the calculations

Comment: So `bc` doesn't seem to be available for some peculiar reason.  What Unix are you running?  Note that this does not mean anything is wrong with your script, only that you system is lacking the `bc` command.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us i) what operating system (if Linux, which one) you are using and ii) show us the output of `type -a bc`.

Comment: I am running putty for my class and I am on the atlas server.

Comment: It does not recognize bc as a command at all terdon

Comment: I kept getting command not found when I tried to solve without bc. Is it not able to do decimal operations and decimal multiplication?

Comment: bc does the arithmetic just fine. The issue is that it cannot be run, because the shell cannot find it. As you are using a remote terminal, the problem is at your server. Run `uname -a` and post the output, please.

Comment: What does "echo $PATH" give you?  Does it contain /usr/bin?

Comment: Yes it does. I figured it out thank you all

Comment: It would be polite to edit your question to show what the problem was. Other people will come to this thread with the same problem, and not benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 2):

> The OP came up with a sensible script, and can't even get to test it because his course stuck him with a broken copy of Linux

it's probably not *a broken copy* of linux.

Be the class hero by doing the following

1. download the program source `bc-1.03.tar.gz` from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bc/
2. upload that .tar.gz file to that server you are working on.
3. `tar -xf bc-1.03.tar.gz`
4. `cd bc-1.03`
5. `./configure`
6. `make`
7. a working executable of `bc` will then be available in this current directory.
8. simply reference this `bc` location in your bash script, example below.
9. open permissions on that file and folder and let your classmates also run it.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
pi=3.14;
circumference=5;
echo "$circumference"
radius=$(echo "$circumference" \* 2 \* "$pi" |/home/ron/bc-1.03/bc -l);
echo "$radius"
area=$(echo "$pi" \* "$radius" \* "$radius" |/home/ron/bc-1.03/bc -l);
echo "$area"
echo "The radius of a circle is $radius";
echo "The area of a circle is $area";
exit
```

Comment: it does not **require** doing `make install`.  In fact, unless you are an administrator having root privilege then *make install* is probably not going to work for you trying to put it under /usr/local/bin..  What I described is all that needs to be done, and that 1.03 version works perfectly fine.  I don't know the current version of `bc` out now... I typed this all up while eating my lunch I figured `ftp.gnu.org` was an acceptable provider of the bc program.

Answer (score 1):

> I am running putty for my class and I am on the atlas server

at the prompt in putty, type `which bc`

it should respond with `/usr/bin/bc`

if it says not found, then it is likely the `bc - An arbitrary precision calculator language` program is not installed on the system you are working on.

if you do an `rpm -qa | grep bc` you should see something like `bc-1.06.95-13.el7.x86_64`.

*There will likely be a few things reported, as it will pattern match many other things like libc and glibc and bcrypt and anything else simply having the letters b and c together.*

If `bc` is installed, and should be found as `/usr/bin/bc` then consider putting the full path of it which is `/usr/bin/bc` in your bash script.  There are security aspects of linux where the PATH environment variable is restricted when in a bash script, however `/usr/bin` definitely would not be blocked or left out so more than likely bc is not installed on that atlas server you are on.

**There is nothing wrong with your posted code**.  Exactly as posted it runs just fine for me on RHEL 7, the output being

```
5
31.40
3095.914400
The radius of a circle is 31.40
The area of a circle is 3095.914400
```

Comment: fyi a helpful sanity check is doing `echo $PATH` in your script and observe what that environment variable is when used in the script.  Then do `echo $PATH` at the terminal prompt, and see if there is a difference.  If the one printed out from within the script is shorter then there's some security aspect being imposed.

Comment: `bc` could be installed in a non standard location, which will be available at the prompt but within your bash script that non standard location isn't coming through for the PATH environment variable.  So if `bc` is installed simply put the correct full path to it in your script to make it happen.

Comment: `rpm -q bc` or `rpm -qf /usr/bin/bc`. Piping -qa thru `grep` is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

with your code, the radius turns out to be bigger than the circumference.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
pi=3.14;
circumference=5;
echo "$circumference"
radius=$(echo "$circumference" / 2 / "$pi" |bc -l);
echo "$radius"
area=$(echo "$pi" \* "$radius" \* "$radius" |bc -l);
echo "$area"
echo "The radius of a circle is $radius";
echo "The area of a circle is $area";
exit
```

Comment: Good spot on the math, but it is not going to fix "bc: command not found" so not actually an answer to the question.

Comment: The code of conduct says to be nice.  I was under the impression two people with an immense reputation were going to let him be a laughing stock.

Comment: No mirth involved. The OP came up with a sensible script, and can't even get to test it because his course stuck him with a broken copy of Linux. I share his frustration.

Comment: Could just be a messed up $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Just type

```bash
sudo apt install bc
```

It should install `bc` on your machine but make sure you are an administrator tho

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that your answer assumes (1) that the problem is indeed a missing program, instead of e.g. wrong environment setup, and (2) that the operating system uses `.deb` packages. Neither is guaranteed (from the little information the OP provided), so you may want to add a precautoniary note to your answer.